# How do you add a video into a master-detail application?

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.5

My app contains a Master View with tableview cells, which, when clicked, goes to a detail view. I'm currently using the latest version of xcode (4.5), and I would appreciate any help on how to go about coding a video into my app. This video should be wifi independent.